# IDLE Python wants googletagmanager.com why?

Tags: google-tag-manager, python-idle

When I start IDLE for Python 3.5.2 it wants to go to googletagmanager.com.

Have anyone experienced the same thing and know how to turn it off?

As the connection to googletagmanager.com only happens when I launch IDLE and disappears when I close the program it has to be connected to IDLE.

Strangely enough lsof -i gives

```
googletagmanager.com:53252 (ESTABLISHED)
python3.5 3771 nomouseisdead    3u  IPv4  34002      0t0  TCP googletagmanager.com:54790->googletagmanager.com:53252
```

I have redirected it to 127.0.0.1 as of now but want to get rid of it.

```
python3.5 -m idlelib
```

did not give any error message.

Running python from console

```
$ python
```

does not connect to the internet.

This is the path

/usr/bin/idle-python3.5

Here is a video. Conky shows what is going on in the bottom right corner

https://vimeo.com/219960249

Comment: Something is uniquely wrong with your system or installation.  IDLE does not 'want' to open random web pages.  Your last 'sentence' appears to be two sentences mashed together; I cannot understand it.  You need to describe what you actually did with more details.  If you have not yet, run IDLE from console with 'python -m idlelib' and see it you get any warnings or errors printed in the console.

Comment: Yes something is seriously wrong. I do not believe I have done something exceptional. sudo apt-get install, then pip install for the rest.

Comment: I haven't seen this before. I have heard of some software packages using Google analytics to track usage, and that's probably what's happening here, but I don't know of any packages that would be running as soon as you launch IDLE which would do that.

Comment: I watched the video and the thought occurred to me, "I'm watching malware in action."  To check, I would recursively grep .../lib for 'google'.  For 3.6.1, using IDLE's Find in Files, I get 177 hits.  They all look innocuous: google-chrome, google copyright, googlebot, safe-looking x.google.com in tests or docstrings, etcetera.  (A large chunk are from pip, which IDLE does not run.)

Comment: It must be obfuscated. I have found thousands of pages of adblocker-urls but nothing relating to IDLE. Installing IDLE requires three packages. I will look into those files to see if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

$ `cat /usr/bin/idle`

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from idlelib.PyShell import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

$ `grep -i 'googletagmanager' /usr/lib/python*/idlelib/*`